# Get a changed src of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, wikipedia

I'm making a project involving a Wikipedia page inside of iframe element. At first, I set iframe's `src` to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random`, so that it changes to a random article. How do I get iframe's URL after it got redireted?

I tried checking `document.querySelector('#first-iframe').src`, but it says `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random`.

I've also tried something like this:

```
for(e in document.querySelector('#first-iframe')) {
    if(document.querySelector('#first-iframe')[e] == null) continue;
    console.log({'key':e, 'val':document.querySelector('#first-iframe')[e]})
}
```

and inside of the a log found nothing.

I've heard I should use `document.querySelector('#first-iframe').contentWindow.window.href` or `document.querySelector('#first-iframe').contentWindow.location.href`, but on both of these I get
`Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.` error.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think it is possible on a cross domain iframe. Iframes have been used for security exploits over the years and browsers are very restrictive on accessing them when they have a different origin

Comment: There are old solutions around using MutationObserver but I couldn't get them working using Wikipedia in modern browser